# JavaScript variable color in JetBrains WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Why JS variables have **different** colors in JetBrains WebStorm 2016 ? There are no significant differences between `express`, `path`, `favicon`... variables: I use them all in the code.

Do these colors mean something, is it normal behavior of WebStorm? If not - how to change them?

[image: Variable colors in JetBrains WebStorm]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The colours for those member fields are different because they are different types.

The fields coloured purple are object variables and the fields in light orange are function variables.

IntelliJ (or WebStorm) has determined this by examining the export field of the targeted JavaScript files.

See screenshots below:

[image: Screenshot showing syntax highlight colour of JavaScript instance functions]

[image: Screenshot showing syntax highlight colour of JavaScript instance variables]

Answer (score 1):

Open Settings/Preferences dialog, and under the File node, click Colors & Fonts and select JavaScript. From right panel you can change all the colors

It's important to note that the check box Use inherited attributes is selected!

For more detail go to this link

[Change Colors](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html)

Comment: For Global variable (my case) it is set to some color (`path` in my code has a such color) but my question is why other variables are shown with other colors?

Comment: Its about your installed color schema. If you wanna you can find different color schemas and install it on  settings.

Comment: Current schema is `Darcula`, but there isn't  any information about variables' different colors in it. The only color `A9B7C6` is set. I changed schema to `Monokai` or `Cobalt` but in these cases they have different colors too. I don't see any logical difference between my variables, so why they should have different colors? I can guess that by mistake some of them are treated as a functions, so they have function's color... But it's not a solution.