# What's mean IntelliJ have different colors in JavaScript with the same import?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea

I have two imports in different projects. I am using IntelliJ with JavaScript.
This image the import shows in purple

[image]

And this one shows in gray:

[image]

What does that mean? I need to figure out this because the imports behave differently.
Pls your guide. I am using React.

Answer (score 1):

Likely indicates different types, similar to [JavaScript variable color in JetBrains WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580773/javascript-variable-color-in-jetbrains-webstorm)

If they're in different projects, they may be importing completely different symbols, even with the same package and names.

Comment: is so great, let me check.

Comment: FYI in my case, I deleted the .idea folder and now the imports show the same color.